# Undo git merge but add commits made after a merge

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I merged two branches that shouldn't have been merged: A & B. I want to undo that merge, and I can easily do that, returning to the last unmerged state of branch A. However, I want to merge individual commits made to a branch A+B after a merge. They don't do anything with files that were affected on branch B, so theoretically it would cause no conflicts. However, when I try to merge this individual commits, I also end up merging branch B as well. How can I merge just the changes made in this precious commits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `git cherry-pick` to select specific commits to apply to the tree.

Alternatively, if the merge was not fast-forwarded, you can revert the merge commit:

```
git revert -m <mainline> <merge_commit>
```